# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 onto a computer that already has Windows 7 Pro installed

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, gpt

System:  ASUS P8H67-M Pro motherboard with latest BIOS update (AMI 3904, 4/27/2013); Intel Core i7-3770 CPU;  Western Digital WD1001FALS-40U9B0 1 TB SATA fixed disk, where all Windows 7 related software resides; this hard drive has a 100 MB EFI System Partition, a 128 MB MicroSoft Reserved (MSR) Partition, and a 931.29 GB NTFS partition; Western Digital WD10EZEX-00UD2A0 1 TB SATA fixed disk with 931.51 GB of unallocated space; Auria EQ 2668 26" LCD monitor.

#### History:

1. Downloaded `ubuntu-13.04-destop-amd64.iso` file and burned an iso DVD. Tried to install from iso DVD, but the installation program could not detect any existing operating system.
2. Downloaded Parted Magic (per Ubuntu web site recommendation) and booted it to run the following: `gdisk /dev/sdb` (WD1001FALS), `p` (indicated everything was OK), `x` (expert command), `n` (to generate new protective MBR), `w` (to save changes).  This procedure had no effect on the Ubuntu 13.04 install process, which could still not detect Windows 7.
3. Per another Ubuntu web site recommendation, I created a 200 MB EFI system partition on the second hard drive (WD10EZEX, intended location for all Linux software). After I booted up the Ubuntu 13.04 installation CD and selected Ubuntu installation from the command line menu, the monitor screen went blank - no graphic display, no display of any kind. I turned off the computer manually by holding down the on-off button. The computer could reboot into Windows 7. I tried booting into Parted Magic and again got a blank screen. I used `diskpart` under the Windows 7 command line to perform a clean command on WD10EZEX and eliminate its EFI partition.  I could again boot into Parted Magic and into the 13.04 installation disk and get displays.
4. Per a Rod Smith web article on ["Legacy BIOS Issues with GPT"](http://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html), I executed the following: `gdisk /dev/sdb/`, `x`, `h` (to recompute CHS values in the protective MBR), `w`(to save changes and exit).
5. I again tried to install Ubuntu 13.04 and got the same message at the Installation type window:

   > This computer currently has no detected operating systems.  What would you like to do?

   If I select "something else" I get a window showing that `sda` (WD10EZEX) has no partitions and `sdb` (WD1001FALS) has an `sdb1` efi partition, an `sdb2` unknown (I assume this is the MSR partition), and an `sdb3` ntfs partition.

#### Question:

Can I create `/`, /swap, and `/home` partitions onto `sda`, go ahead with the installation, and be able to boot into either Windows 7 or Ubuntu 13.04?  I am willing to switch from disk-to-disk in the in the BIOS initialization process when I turn the computer on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install Ubuntu whereever you like and it will be the boot loader (grub) that'll enable you to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Thank you.  My main concern is to loose ability to boot up in windows once ubuntu is installed.  I will give it a try.  ChetB

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 13.04, using the "something else" option, with / , /swap, and /home partitions on the second hard drive (WD10EZEX).  The installation appears to have been successful.  The grub boot loader has not shown up.  If I turn on the PC it automatically boots up into Windows 7 (all on WD1001FALS).  If I go into the BIOS at turn-on to select the boot source, I can choose either Windows 7 or Ubunbu 13.04, which is OK with me.    Again, thank you very much for your help.